# Adding A fallback Image {HTML&CSS}

Tags: html, css, image, web, text

I created a text app on Atom text editor using pure HTML&CSS.
I imported all the required Images&Icons from a folder that I created within the editor named "images". {i did not use the "URL" "HTTPS" src to direct towards images.)

Now, when I publish my work on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Omer-XXD/pen/KKqPMQq)
it shows the "unknown image" icon BCS I am unable to add my "image" folder there.

Since I can't add my folder in CodePen, the question of which the answer I require is:

***How can I add a fallback image src, a "URL or HTTPS" in my code??***

Here is my code {directrion of images} :

```
 <header>
      <nav>
        <ul class = "nav_links">
          <!-- <li><a class = "link_1" href : '#'>Home</li></a>  -->
           <!-- <li><a class = "link_2" href : '#'>Home</li></a> -->
           <!-- <li><a class = "link_3" href : '#'></li></a>  -->
          <li> <a class ="back-button" href = "#"> < </a> </li>
          <li> <img class = "dp" src = "images\pew.jpg"> </li>
          <li> <a class = "username" href="images/wp6890841.png">LunaticXXD_10</a></li>
          <li><img class="more-button" src ="images\more.png"></a></li>
          <li> <a class= "call-button" href ="#"><img class = "call-me" src = "images\whitecall.png"></a></li>
          <li> <button class = "block-contact" type = "submit">Block Contact</button></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use https://imgur.com/ as an image storage. Upload your image there then after its done, right click on your image and select "copy image address". You can then use this address to directly link an image to your html code.

An image address you copied should look something like this:

`https://i.imgur.com/vqMT5kq.jpg`

Example image applied to your code:

`<img class = "dp" src = "https://i.imgur.com/vqMT5kq.jpg">`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Sca64LW
Thanks, mate :) But, is there a way to add multiples images {One as a backup/Fallback} similar to adding browser fallbacks on HTML or fallback fonts.
Use that image as a wallpaper, deeming it as thanks from me.